# Explicit Discrete Fourier Transform to Kronecker Delta?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, fourier-analysis

How can I have mathematica automatically simplify expressions like this

```
Sum[Exp[-I x k], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

using

```
KroneckerDelta[k]
```

? Evaluating the above using Simplify produces: Sum does not converge.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`FourierSequenceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSequenceTransform):

```
FourierSequenceTransform[1, x, k]
```

> 2 π DiracDelta[k]